# How to get rid of white-space at the bottom of div element when text is entered

Tags: css, html

I have a blank HTML page and I want to align 2 elements...*Vertically and Horizontally*. These elements are a `<img>` tag, a `<p>` tag for text, and 2 `<div>` tags for containing those elements...

When I resize my window I don't want these elements to be cut-off by my browser. After countless hours of trying to figure this out, and searching Stack and various other websites...I came close, but I could never get it 100% like I want it...

There's this white-space at the bottom and the ride side of the bordered second div near the text, and the culprit appears to be the `<p>`. When I get rid of the tag the white-space goes away. However, I want the text under the image so I need it...

[image: content alignment problem]
[image: content alignment problem 2]

The white-space is making me question whether the content is placed in the center or not. How can I get rid of it?

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
      <p>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/blue/square-xxl.png" alt="Under Construction"></a>
        <br> UNDER CONSTRUCTION!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    margin:0;
    background-color: seagreen;
} 

#container
{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    min-width:400px;
} 


#content 
{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    outline:3px solid red;

}

#content p 
{
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Courier;
    font-size:48px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    color:springgreen;
}
```

Comment: Can you identify in the image which white-space you want to remove? Or show an image of what you like your page to look like.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll add another image

Comment: A picture has been added

Comment: I appreciate all your answers. I get different results across different browsers, so I can't really check anybody's answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed you HTML to enclose your text in a `span` tag and removed the `br`:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
      <p>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/blue/square-xxl.png" alt="Under Construction"></a>
        <span>UNDER CONSTRUCTION!</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Then I added this to your CSS. It styles the enclosing `span` as a block, so you don't need to `<br>` tag in your HTML. It also uses line-height to adjust spacing above and below the line of text.

```
#content span {
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
   line-height: .8;
}
```

And removed the `position` attribute from here:

```
#container
{
    /*position:relative;*/ /* Removed */
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   min-width:400px;
}
```

Here is a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/029383d6/)

**UPDATE**

It appears the reason why you are seeing white-space still on Firefox is that you are using [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/outline) instead of [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border?v=control) on your CSS for `#content`.

I don't know exactly why Firefox is rendering the outline differently. But if you change your CSS for `#content` to the following, you'll get the same result on Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE (11).:

```
#content 
{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    /*outline:3px solid red;*/
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/029383d6/2/)

Comment: Is it possible to do this without the use of a arbitrary number like `.8`. I'm curious to what's causing the whitespace to be there in the first place. Even on the inside right of the div near the text there's white-space...I don't know why its so hard to get my elements to spread across evenly inside the div with equal white-space on all sides, WHILE maintaining center alignment within the html page. I've been sitting at my computer for HOURS trying to figure this out...

Comment: `line-height` is used for line spacing. You can remove it which will set `line-height` to 1 (or 100%). I set it as 0.8 (or 80%) since your text are in uppercase, so you don't need the space that is allocated under the text base, for letters like "g", "p", "q".

Comment: There is some white-space after the exclamation point since you are using fixed-width font (ie, Courier). So your exclamation point will occupy the same width as an "A" or "W". Try changing your font to one which does not have fixed width, like Arial.

Comment: The CSS `line-height` property attribute will not really solve anything.

Comment: @FrankFajardo also thank you for the explanation. Didn't really think about the monospace

Comment: Interesting...On my Windows the jsfiddle shows line-height working in Chrome...But on my Linux box firefox doesn't even acknowledge it...

Comment: @PrimRock, I added an update as to how it can work on Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through your code . i have made some changes in above given code . I hope this gone be helpful to you. 
**CSS**

```css
body
{
    margin:0;
    background-color: seagreen;
} 
img{
display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
/* add this css to remove the white space under text */
p
{
margin-bottom: -9px !important;
}
#container
{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    min-width:400px;
 
} 


#content 
{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    outline:3px solid red;
     margin-top: 200px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#content p 
{
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Courier;
    font-size:48px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    color:springgreen;
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
    <div id="content">

        <a href="index.html"><img src="http://spectrumapartments.com.au/wp-content/themes/spectrumapartments/img/building/red-squares.png" alt="Under Construction"></a>
        <br> 
  <p>UNDER CONSTRUCTION!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without the use of a arbitrary number like `-9px` in `margin-bottom:-9px`. I'm curious to what's causing the whitespace to be there in the first place. Even on the inside right of the div near the text there's white-space...I don't know why its so hard to get my elements to spread across evenly inside the div with equal white-space on all sides, WHILE maintaining center alignment within the html page. I've been sitting at my computer for HOURS trying to figure this out...

Comment: @PrimRock Yes, you can change the value of margin-bottom to any number .But in your case ,this is it is best suited for your situation. **CSS _margin-bottom_ properties are used to generate(if its value is in +ve) or remove(if its value is in -ve) space around elements.**

Comment: Actually, that white-space near right of the div is due to <code>font-family: Courier;</code> under <code> #content p</code> in **CSS** Code. You  remove white-spaces from right side either by changing font-family Courier to another font family for instance **font-family: sans-serif;** or just remove this property.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I didn't really think about monospace, but it makes a lot of sense now that I'm realizing it...Also, I get different results with the snippet code on Firefox and Chrome. Chrome gets rid of the bottom completely leaving a bit a the top. While firefox leaves whitespace at both top and bottom.

Answer (score -1):

**I GAVE IT ANOTHER TRY, HOPEFULLY THIS WILL SOLVE IT FOR YOU. YOU SOUND VERY DESPERATE.**

```css
*{
  border: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
}
.container {
    font-size: 0;
}
.container span {
    font-size: 35px;
    background: #ff8ea1;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
}

.container span.no-space {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: .75em;
    line-height: .75em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span>Under Construction</span>
    <div style="height: 20px;"></div>
    <span class="no-space">Under Construction</span>
</div>
```

**TRY THIS ONE!**

Comment: Not the box. That box is a place holder lol.I should make that more clear

Comment: Which? I cannot see the white-space?

Comment: I already have `margin:0;`, but adding `padding:0;` to my `<p>` didn't help either...

Comment: You do not have padding: 0px; in your CSS above.

Comment: I'm aware I don't have the padding attribute added to my post here, but I did add it to my code on my computer and tested it myself. Unfortunately, its still unsuccessful

Comment: Remove the whie-space attribute.

Comment: I'm positive `whitespace:nowrap;` has nothing to do with it...That attribute is for text breaking itself when resizing the browser. I removed it anyways, and still no luck

Comment: LOL! word-wrap:break-word; and word-break:break-all; are used for that.

Comment: `whitespace:nowrap;` can be used for it too. Read the properties section https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: Nope. I am sorry. `White-space: nowrap;` is used to wrap words or text that you do not want to break at all.

Comment: LOL That's what I was using it for, if I wasn't clear about that. I wasn't trying to break the text I was trying to prevent it from doing so xD

Comment: @PrimRock, _if I wasn't clear about that_ **no you weren't clear about that.** Are you some kid, that never worked with this stuff before? TO much LOLing around.

Comment: *Never worked with this stuff this before*, *kid*.....Technically you haven't either **kid** because you just threw 1 irrelevant suggestion and 2 others that didn't work that I been tried ahead of time. Your help is appreciated of course, but if you don't know what you're talking...Do us a favor, and stop spamming in the comments. Good day....

Comment: You have provided insufficient information for anyone to really tackle this problem. May I suggest you EDIT your question and make it clearer.

Comment: Now that's much, much better.

Comment: @PrimRock, things look so different in my browser when I run your code.

Comment: @PrimRock, my last question before I continue with this, do you want this to follow W3C Standards and Validation?

Comment: Yes, always...If I'm doing something that violates the standard please enlighten me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146930/discussion-between-john-smith-and-primrock).